# whats wrong with this query?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO print_development.categories (id, name)
VALUES (select id, name  from print_pro.categories where parent_id is NULL);

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id, name  from print_pro.categories where parent_id is NULL)' at line 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong INSERT/SELECT syntax. You don't use "VALUES", just use the SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO print_development.categories (id, name)
select id, name  from print_pro.categories where parent_id is NULL
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Exactly, but wrong manual page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html